I was totally off on you
On a TV show, the guests are shown 5 people and are listened to them with a short sentence, who could sound as UK or US accents, and the guests are expect to guess where they really are from. One of the people seemed like a American but sounded very British and the guest told him:
I WAS TOTALLY OFF ON YOU. UK or US (see:3:50-3:55)
What does this mean? Does it mean I was sure about you?

They were all going 'You were good!'. That guy was crap.

The guests listen to them saying a short sentence.

To be "off" (an adjective) means to be incorrect.  You might say about "30+60=100", "This calculation is off (by ten)"
and "on" (a preposition in this case) means "about or concerning". You might say, "A book on mathematics"
It's casual, but bad English, to use "off" and "on" like this.
